# superagent Access-Control-Allow-Origin error

Tags: http, cors, superagent, http-method

I'm using superagent v3.8.3 I got `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` CORS error.

```
import request from 'superagent'
request(
        APIS.IAMPORT.GET_TOKEN.method,
        APIS.IAMPORT.GET_TOKEN.path()
      )
        .withCredentials()
        .send({
          imp_key: config.iamport.apiKey,
          imp_secret: config.iamport.secretKey
        })
        .end((err, res) => {
          if (err) reject(err)
          else resolve(res.body)
        })
```

I tried to use `.withCredentials()`, but it doesn't work.
I got this error message from api.

apply?id=21:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.iamport.kr/users/getToken' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

However, I can get result when I'm using postman.

I think remove OPTION http method is gonna work. but I'm not sure how can I solve this problem.

How can solve this? thanks.

Comment: @sideshowbarker you mean, I can't use that api call?

Comment: You can use that API from your backend code but as far as your frontend code goes, yeah I mean you can’t use that API call — not from your frontend code.

Comment: thanks, when I call request in my backend code It works.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not regarding HTTP method. Issue is CORS and has been tried to explain the cause and resolutions in another answer. Please refer the link below:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54867814/6356369